# S3 to Redshift: Unknown boolean format

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Executing a copy command from S3 to Redshift, loading JSON files. I have some fields as bool in a new table I'm inserting into and always getting the following error: "Unknown boolean format"

My JSON is well parsed, ran a million tests on that already. I've tried passing in the boolean fields as:

```
false  //  "false"  //  "False"  //  0  //  "0"  //  null
```

But always get the same error, when executing:

```
select * from stl_load_errors;

err_code  err_reason
1210      Unknown boolean format
```

I've seen some comments about using IGNOREHEADER in my statement but that isn't an option because the files I'm dealing with are in a single row json format. Ignoring the head would basically mean not reading thefile at all. I have other tables working like this and work fine, but don't have any bool columns in those tables.

Comment: can you share some sample json and our copy command..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [COPY from JSON Format](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html) documentation page provides an example that includes a Boolean:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "guid": "84512477-fa49-456b-b407-581d0d851c3c",
    "isActive": true,
    "tags": [
        "nisi",
        "culpa",
        "ad",
        "amet",
        "voluptate",
        "reprehenderit",
        "veniam"
    ],
    "friends": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Carmella Gonzales"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Renaldo"
        }
    ]
}
```

The [Boolean](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Boolean_type.html) documentation page shows values similar to what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Turns out the jsonformat file had 2 fields in the wrong order and was confusing bool with another datatype -_-